# Jquery ui icons are not showing

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu").menu({
 icons:{submenu:"ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"}
 });
});
</script>
```

I've tried this code but icons on google are not visible?
Error on developer tool is
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
I've tried including the image folder from jquery-ui zip file but the icons are not showing up

Comment: What is `#menu` referring to? If that is all your code, that element does not exist and so the jQuery code will not produce the result you are aiming for.

Comment: #menu is the id of unordered list

Comment: I only pasted the jquery part.rest is the html part which i didn't include